# How do I stop Android from auto-killing an app?

Tags: android

How do I stop Android from auto-killing an app?
My radio app auto-killed after 5:15 minutes. I need my radio player work all time and Not be killed .
i use `startForegroundCompat` but not work good and still auto-killed after 15 : 20 minutes

```
package com.test.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class StreamService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "StreamService";
    MediaPlayer mp;
    boolean isPlaying;
    Intent MainActivity;

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Notification n;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    // Change this int to some number specifically for this app
    int notifId = 85;

     private OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener =
              new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
                      public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                        switch (focusChange) {

                               case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) :
                               // Lower the volume while ducking.
                               mp.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
                               break;
                               case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) :
                               mp.pause();
                               break;

                               case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) :
                               mp.stop();

                               break;

                               case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) :
                               // Return the volume to normal and resume if paused.
                               mp.setVolume(1f, 1f);
                               mp.start();
                               break;
                               default: break;
    }
    }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        // Init the SharedPreferences and Editor
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        editor = prefs.edit();

        // Set up the buffering notification
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        String notifTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        String notifMessage = context.getResources().getString(R.string.buffering);

        n = new Notification();
        n.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        n.tickerText = "Buffering";
        n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        nIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent, 0);

        n.setLatestEventInfo(context, notifTitle, notifMessage, pIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(notifId, n);

        // It's very important that you put the IP/URL of your ShoutCast stream here

        String url = "http://90.121.123.129:8272";
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            mp.setDataSource(url);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.prepareAsync();
            mp.setOnErrorListener(null);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "IllegalStateException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException");
        }   
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        mp.start();

        // Set the isPlaying preference to true
        editor.putBoolean("isPlaying", true);
        editor.commit();

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String notifTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        String notifMessage = context.getResources().getString(R.string.now_playing);

        n.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        n.tickerText = notifMessage;
        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent, 0);

        n.setLatestEventInfo(context, notifTitle, notifMessage, pIntent);
        // Change 5315 to some nother number
        notificationManager.notify(notifId, n);
    /*
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        // Request audio focus for playback
        int result = am.requestAudioFocus(focusChangeListener,
        // Use the music stream.
        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        // Request permanent focus.
        AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);


        if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
        // other app had stopped playing song now , so u can do u stuff now .

        }
        */

            }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        mp.start();
        // Set the isPlaying preference to true
                editor.putBoolean("isPlaying", true);
                editor.commit();

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                String notifTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
                String notifMessage = context.getResources().getString(R.string.now_playing);

                n.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
                n.tickerText = notifMessage;
                n.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
                n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

                Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent, 0);

                n.setLatestEventInfo(context, notifTitle, notifMessage, pIntent);
                // Change 5315 to some nother number
                notificationManager.notify(notifId, n);
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                // Request audio focus for playback
                int result = am.requestAudioFocus(focusChangeListener,
                // Use the music stream.
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                // Request permanent focus.
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);


                if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                // other app had stopped playing song now , so u can do u stuff now .

                }



        return START_STICKY;
    }
    void startForegroundCompat(int id, Notification notification) {
        // If we have the new startForeground API, then use it.

            mp.start();

            return;

        }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
        editor.putBoolean("isPlaying", false);
        editor.commit();
        notificationManager.cancel(notifId);
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        am.abandonAudioFocus(focusChangeListener);


    }

}
```

Comment: You should instead check if your app is not abusing Android ecosystem. It's probably consuming too much memory. Check for memory leaks. Use analyzer tools to find the reason.

Comment: Did you mean `onStartCommand ...return START_STICKY;` ?

Comment: i am anew android developer:)

Comment: I meant that you are not following Android fundamental principles and your app is very quickly in the queue of processes to be killed. You should share your code and let us see what you might be doing wrong. But honestly, I would also suggest to start with Android tutorials and then create your own app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this, and you should never do this. It's Android who decides what app should be running, and what should be killed. You must design your application to handle such situations and save sensitive data

Comment: Did you mean `onStartCommand ...return START_STICKY;` ?

Comment: Please consider using services for background tasks http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html. Also, take a look at Saving Data options http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html